# Spring cloud Stream Kafka: Get acknowledgement for processor.output().send(message);

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to know whether the write to kafka topic was successful with spring-cloud-stream.

```
public boolean writeToKafka(String emails) {

        Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(emails).build();
        return processor.output().send(message);

    }
```

The return statements always evaluates to true. I need send back ack to calling method whether message was written.

Comment: Why do you need the ack? I mean the framework takes care of it for you already, so if you are using the framework why do you want to circumvent?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky. Thanks for the response. The reason is I want to send HTTP status back. If there are any failures writing message to Kafka I want to let the user know so that he retries later.

Comment: You can set `s.c.s.kafka.bindings.output.producer.sync=true` to block the calling thread until the send completes (or an exception is thrown).

Comment: Thanks Gray Russell. Its working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Gray Russell for the answer. I just added the below property in application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.sync=true
```